Update the on-topic page to link to GenAI Stack Exchange and state that prompt design questions are generally off-topic
Our on-topic page (partially written by me) contains links to related or similar sites to our site in the section Overlapping Sites. We should probably include the link to https://genai.stackexchange.com/ there.
In the section Specific topics, close to Natural language processing and understanding, we should also include the link to GenAI, in same way that we're already linking to (6)
Moreover, given Are questions about prompt-design on-topic here? and that Dennis' answer received a lot of upvotes and he stated "prompt design / prompt engineering questions would often be off-topic here", there seems to be a consensus that prompt design questions are generally off-topic here.
So, in summary, a moderator should

add https://genai.stackexchange.com/ to the Overlapping Sites section in the on-topic page
add a statement like "Prompt design/engineering questions are generally off-topic" to the Off-topic section of the same page


Thanks for flagging. I agree with all suggested changes. Done.
